# Can complex conjugation change convergence mode?

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

$\newcommand{\compconj}[1]{%
 \overline{#1}%
}$

Let $f$ be holomorphic, then I can expand it to a uniform convergent power series at the origin
$$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k(z-0)^k$$
I know that
$$\bar f(z) = \compconj{\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kz^k}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \bar c_k \compconj{z^k}$$

Now I wonder if this series does still converge uniformly?
Because I really need to use
$$\int\sum_{k=0}^\infty \bar c_k \compconj{z^k} dt = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int\bar c_k \compconj{z^k} dz$$
but I am not sure if this is legit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complex conjugate of a uniformly convergent series is a uniformly convergent series.  This is obvious because complex conjugation preserves absolute values.